# Is the category of modules over an abstract monoid enriched?

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, monoidal-categories, enriched-category-theory

If $A$ is an algebra over $\mathbb C$, or, in other words, a [monoid](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monoid+in+a+monoidal+category) in the [closed monoidal category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/closed+monoidal+category) $_{\mathbb C}\operatorname{Vect}$ of all vector spaces over $\mathbb C$, then, clearly, the category $_A\operatorname{Vect}$ of all left $A$-modules is [enriched](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enriched_category) over the category $_{\mathbb C}\operatorname{Vect}$.

Is the same true if we replace $_{\mathbb C}\operatorname{Vect}$ by an arbitrary monoidal closed category $V$?

I.e.,

> if we consider an arbitrary closed monoidal category $V$ and take an arbitrary monoid $A$ in $V$, will the category $_A V$ of all [left $A$-modules](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/module+over+a+monoid) be an enriched category over $V$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need that $V$ has equalizers (but for many basic stuff in the theory of $V$-enriched categories we need $V$ to be complete and cocomplete anyway). I denote internal Homs by $\underline{\mathrm{Hom}}$.

If $\underline{M} = (M, h : A \otimes M \to M)$, $\underline{N} = (N , k : A \otimes N \to N)$ are left $ A$-modules, define $\underline{\mathrm{Hom}}_A(\underline{M},\underline{N})$ as the equalizer of

$$\underline{\mathrm{Hom}}(M, N) \xrightarrow{h^*} \underline{\mathrm{Hom}}(M \otimes A,N)$$

and
$$\underline{\mathrm{Hom}}(M,N) \xrightarrow{(\check{k})_*} \underline{\mathrm{Hom}}(M,\underline{\mathrm{Hom}}(A,N))  \xrightarrow{\cong} \underline{\mathrm{Hom}}(M \otimes A,N).$$

A reference for this is Proposition 1.2.17 in F. Marty, *Des ouverts Zariski et des morphismes lisses en géométrie relative*.

Comment: Martin, excuse me, for constructing this morphism
$$
\operatorname{Hom}(M,N)\to \operatorname{Hom}(M,\operatorname{Hom}(A,N)),
$$
I think we need the transformation of symmetry,
$$
X\otimes Y\to Y\otimes X,
$$
is that true? So your construction seems to work only for symmetric monoidal categories? (Or, I don't know, perhaps, all closed monoidal categories are assumed to be symmetric?)

Comment: No, one uses (see my notation) the morphism $N \to \underline{\mathrm{Hom}}(A,N)$ which is adjoint to $A \otimes N \to N$. A symmetry is not necessary.

Comment: (At least I *think* that it is not necessary. But I work with symmetric monoidal categories most of the time, so better doublecheck this.)

Comment: Martin, forgive me for waking up again. I look at this thread from time to time, trying to restore the details, and you know, I don't understand how the morphism $[L,M]\otimes [M,N]\to [L,N]$ is constructed. I mean for being a $V$-enriched category, $_AV$ must have a family of morphisms $[L,M]\otimes [M,N]\to [L,N]$. I suppose they are defined as equalizers as well, but I don't understand why the corresponding diagrams are commutative. Is there a simple way to explain this?

Answer (score 5):

**Fact**: an homomorphism of $A$-modules (for a monoid $A$ in a monoidal category $V$) is a map $f : M \to N$ such that $f(a.m)=a.fm$, or in purely diagrammatic form $f\circ \rho = \rho'\circ (A\otimes f)$, where $\rho : A \otimes M \to M$ and $\rho' : A\otimes N \to N$ are the actions that make $M,N$ two $A$-modules.

But then, the subobject of "homomorphisms of modules" is just the subobject of the hom-object $V(M,N)$ defined as the equaliser of two maps
$$
\rho^* : V(M,N) \to V(A\otimes M,N)
$$
and
$$
\rho'_* \circ (A\otimes \_) : V(M,N) \to V(A\otimes M,A\otimes N) \to V(A\otimes M,N)
$$

This definition gives you precisely what you want when the hom-objects are sets, but id "elementless".

Also, I'm using a general construction in a particular case: $A$-modules are algebras for the monad $T_A=A\otimes \_$, and $A$-module homomorphisms are $T_A$-algebra morphisms. If $T$ is any monad on a category $V$, the subobject of $T$-algebra morphisms between two $T$-algebras $(M, m : TM \to M)$ and $(N, n : TN \to N)$ is the equaliser of the pair of morphisms
$$ m^* : V(M,N) \to V(TM,N) \qquad 
n_* \circ T_{MN} : V(M,N) \to V(TM,TN) \to V(TM, N)
$$

Comment: Fosco, I don't understand this detail:
$$
V(M,N)\to V(A\otimes M,A\otimes N).
$$
To construct this morphism, we need a morphism $A\otimes M\to M$ and a morphism $N\to A\otimes N$, what are these two morphisms? Or I am missing something?

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov No, one uses that $A \otimes -$ is a $V$-functor.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: Martin, do you mean a functor between enriched categories?

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov Yes.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: Martin, excuse me my ignorance, I need a text where this is written.

Comment: An "enriched functor" consists of a function at the level of objects, and *for each pair of objects $X,Y$*, a morphism $F_{XY} : \hom(X,Y) \to \hom(FX,FY)$ in the base of enrichment, where the hom's live. If you need a reference, I guess any book where this definition is spelled out in full will do.

Comment: Fosco, I have only MacLane and Tsalenko-Shulgeifer. I don't see this result about $\operatorname{hom}(X,Y)\to\operatorname{hom}(A\otimes X,A\otimes Y)$ there. How do they construct this morphism?

Comment: First lines of page 9: http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/10/tr10.pdf

Comment: Fosco, Kelly's page 9 contains the definition of $V$-functor, but not the explanation of why $A\otimes \_$ is a $V$-functor.

Comment: Try to cook the usual recipe (it's called "exercise for the reader") for when you have a definition and a putative example, and you're hungry for a proof. :)

Comment: Ah, yes, in your universe $\operatorname{hom}(X,Y)\to\operatorname{hom}(A\otimes X,A\otimes Y)$ is equivalent to $\operatorname{hom}(X,Y)\otimes A\otimes X \to A\otimes Y$. You can go crazy with your science. However, this requires the transformation of symmetry.