# How is the morphism of composition in the enriched category of modules constructed?

Tags: category-theory, monoidal-categories, enriched-category-theory

In April, I asked the [question of how the structure of the enriched category is introduced into the category $_AV$ of modules over a given monoid $A$ in a closed monoidal category $V$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4121153/is-the-category-of-modules-over-an-abstract-monoid-enriched):

> if we consider an arbitrary closed monoidal category $V$ and take an arbitrary monoid $A$ in $V$, will the category $_A V$ of all [left $A$-modules](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/module+over+a+monoid) be an enriched category over $V$?

People explained to me the construction of the object of morphisms $V(M,N)$, I am grateful to them, and I accepted their answer, but, forgive me for my carelessness, now I began to write down the proof, and I realized that I did not understand how the ["enriched" composition morphism](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/enriched+category) is constructed in $_AV$:
$$
\circ_{L,M,N}:V(M,N)\otimes V(L,M)\to V(L,N).
$$
I suppose that this must be the "lift to the equalizer" of the cone
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
V(M,N)\otimes V(L,M)\to \underline{\operatorname{Hom}}(M,N)\otimes \underline{\operatorname{Hom}}(L,M)\to \underline{\operatorname{Hom}}(L,N)
\end{equation}
for the pair of morphisms that define $V(L,N)$ as their equalizer:
$$
\underline{\operatorname{Hom}}(L,N)\to \underline{\operatorname{Hom}}(A\otimes L,N)
$$
and
$$
\underline{\operatorname{Hom}}(L,N)\to \underline{\operatorname{Hom}}(L, \underline{\operatorname{Hom}}(A,N)) \to \underline{\operatorname{Hom}}(A\otimes L,N)
$$
(here $\underline{\operatorname{Hom}}$ means the inner hom-functor in $V$).
But the problem for me is that I don't understand why (1) is indeed a cone for this pair, i.e.

> why the two morphisms
> $$
> V(M,N)\otimes V(L,M)\to \underline{\operatorname{Hom}}(M,N)\otimes \underline{\operatorname{Hom}}(L,M)\to \underline{\operatorname{Hom}}(L,N)\to \underline{\operatorname{Hom}}(A\otimes L,N)
> $$
> and
> $$
> V(M,N)\otimes V(L,M)\to \underline{\operatorname{Hom}}(M,N)\otimes \underline{\operatorname{Hom}}(L,M)\to \underline{\operatorname{Hom}}(L,N)\to \underline{\operatorname{Hom}}(L, \underline{\operatorname{Hom}}(A,N)) \to \underline{\operatorname{Hom}}(A\otimes L,N)
> $$
> coincide.

Can anybody enlighten me?

**Edit.** Those who are interested can estimate the level of difficulties. For the proof I had to construct 40 diagrams, but this is not enough, because I deduce everything from the following lemma, which I still cannot prove:

> **Lemma.** For each objects $A$, $X$, $Y$ and each morphism $\mu:A\otimes Y\to Y$ the following two morphisms coincide:
> $$
> \underline{\operatorname{Hom}}(X,Y)\otimes A\otimes X\to 
> \underline{\operatorname{Hom}}(X,\underline{\operatorname{Hom}}(A,Y))\otimes A\otimes X\to 
> \underline{\operatorname{Hom}}(A\otimes X,Y)\otimes A\otimes X\to Y
> $$
> (were the first arrow is generated by the arrow $Y\to\underline{\operatorname{Hom}}(A,Y)$, which corresponds to the morphism $\mu:A\otimes Y\to Y$), and
> $$
> \underline{\operatorname{Hom}}(X,Y)\otimes A\otimes X\to 
> A\otimes \underline{\operatorname{Hom}}(X,Y)\otimes X\to 
> A\otimes Y\to Y
> $$
> (were the last arrow is the morphism $\mu:A\otimes Y\to Y$).

I have a feeling that I am doing something wrong, because this looks too complicated. Is it possible that there is a trick that allows to simplify everything? And, in particular, how do people prove this lemma?

P.S. I asked this also at [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/404288/how-is-the-morphism-of-composition-in-the-enriched-category-of-modules-construct).